# Como adicionar objetos à uma classe repositório? E como o usuário pode escolher a quantidade de array em que ele vai adicionar os dados?

Tags: java

Olá, minha dúvida é a seguinte. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para ler os dados do usuário na main da seguinte forma: tenho um array de até 10 para o usuário por os dados do livro, mas ele pode escolher menos. E outra, depois do usuário preencher os dados do livro, como adicionar esses livros na classe repositório?
Na main tenho de preencher os livros¹, acessar o toString da classe repositório com todos o livros cadastrados², obter o desconto e por fim imprimir o livro com desconto³.

classe Livro

```
public double obterDesconto(int taxa) {
    return valor - (taxa/100);
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Livro [titulo=" + titulo + ", codigo=" + codigo + ", editora=" + editora + ", valor=" + valor + "]";
}
public Livro(String titulo, String codigo, String editora, double valor) {
    super();
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.editora = editora;
    this.valor = valor;
}
public Livro() {

}




public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getEditora() {
    return editora;
}

public void setEditora(String editora) {
    this.editora = editora;
}

public double getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(double valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}
```

}

Classe repositorio

```
public Repositorio() {
    super();
    livros = new Livro[10];
    livros[0] = new Livro();
    livros[1] = new Livro();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Repositorio [livros=" + Arrays.toString(livros) + "]"+"\n";
}

public Livro obterLivro(String codigo) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(livros[i] != null) {
                if(livros[i].getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
                    return livros[i];
                }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean addLivro(Livro livro) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;)
        if(livros[i] != null)
            return false;
        else {
            livros[i] = livro;
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Primeiro, você pode tirar do seu construtor, na classe repositório aquelas instancias de livros q que você faz ali em cima.

```
 livros[0] = new Livro();
livros[1] = new Livro();
```

Feito isso, no seu main você pode ter um repositório e um scanner:

```
Repositorio repo = new Repositorio();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Com o scanner você pode gravar o que o usuário digitar no console e atribuir à suas variáveis.
Tendo isso, você pode fazer uma lógica simples, utilizando um `while` a alguns `system.out.println`, que vão instruir ao seu usuário que ele pode pressionar 1 para continuar comprando/adicionando livros, ou 2 para finalizar  a compra.
No seu `while` você pode adicionar uma variável auxiliar que contará quantos livros já foram selecionados, você pode usar o valor dessa variável para saber em qual lugar no seu vetor você irá adicionar outro livro.
Dessa forma você pode rever o seu `for`, que está percorrendo o vetor na sua classe repositório.
Então você poderá dizer ao seu `while` que se o auxiliar chegar a 10, ou se o valor de uma variável sair, for 1, por exemplo, você termina o laço.
Sua lógica de desconto, por ser um método e você pode chamar ela antes de inserir o livro, assim sempre antes de adicionar um livro você calcula o desconto dele, se haver.

Já os `toStrings`, para ter o `ToString` de um livro, você precisa apenas dar um `system.out.println(repo.toString);`

Essa é a forma que eu faria, na minha opinião ficaria mais simples. Espero que tenha ajudado de alguma forma!